# Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): zone.filter is not a function

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks, react-map-gl

Here i'm trying to get the mark the place using Mapbox gl and I have installed react-map-gl  It's throwing the above error Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): zone.filter is not a function.
Here i'm trying to get the mark the place using Mapbox gl and I have installed react-map-gl  It's throwing the above error Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): zone.filter is not a function.

could some please help me solve this. What am doing wrong here?

```
HomeZones.js

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactMapGL,{Marker} from 'react-map-gl';

export default class HomeZones extends Component {
    state = {
        viewport : {
            latitude : -41.308734,
            longitude : 174.821595,
            width: "100vw",
            height: "100vh",
            zoom: 10  
        },
        zoneHome : [],
        uLocation : {}
    }

    componentDidMount () {
        this.fetchzone();
    }

    filterZoneHome = zone => {
        return zone.filter(spot => {
            return spot.type === "Polygon";
         });
    };

    fetchzone = () => {
        fetch(`https://api.mevo.co.nz/public/home-zones/all.json`)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(zone => {
            let zoneHom = this.filterZoneHome(zone);
           this.setState({
              zoneHome: zoneHom
           });
         });
      };

      zoneHomeHandler = () => {
        return this.state.zoneHome.map(spot => {
          return (
            <Marker
               latitude={parseFloat(spot.latitude)}
               longitude={parseFloat(spot.longitude)}
            >
              <img src="https://assets.mevo.co.nz/brand/logo-brand.svg" alt="" />
            </Marker>
          );
        });
      };
    render() {
        
        return (
            <div>
        <ReactMapGL {...this.state.viewport}
             mapStyle = "mapbox://styles/aksharvijay/ckklz7npa1jaw17n4c6t5984x"
             onViewportChange = {viewport => this.setState( { viewport})}
             mapboxApiAccessToken = "pk.eyJ1IjoiYWtzaGFydmlqYXkiLCJhIjoiY2trbHh6MXhwMW9vazMxb2R3ajUxODZuaSJ9.nT6OhBEGqYls_SIZPqjw1w"
             >
                 {Object.keys(this.state.uLocation).length !== 0 ? (
                     <Marker
                     latitude = {this.state.uLocation.lat}
                     longitude = {this.state.uLocation.long}>
                         <img src="https://assets.mevo.co.nz/brand/logo-brand.svg" alt="" />
                     </Marker>
                 ) : (
                     <div></div>
                 )
                
                }
                {this.zoneHomeHandler}
            </ReactMapGL>
                
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is that your fetch result is an object (`.json()` returns javascript object) while `filter` is an array method.

I suppose that you want to filter coordinates of this result, so you have to  get `coordinates` array from this object. Look at the `https://api.mevo.co.nz/public/home-zones/all.json` and study the structure of the object.

Comment: Yes, Thats what i'm trying to do and mark the places based on the lat and long. Could you please tell me what I'm supposed to correct @wwilkowski

Comment: I'm not sure what's your goal. You fetch only one object with property `type` inside `geometry` inside `data`... Did you see structure of the result object? Tell me, what you want to do exactly with that. You can get `type` of this object like `x.data.geometry.type` but you have only one object. As I see in your code, you expect array of objects.

Comment: {
    "iconUrl": "",
    "position": {
      "latitude": "-41.291099",
      "longitude": "174.786042"
    }
  },
  {
    "iconUrl": "",
    "position": {
      "latitude": "-41.317825",
      "longitude": "174.815709"
    }
  }

Using this and above json i'm trying to position the item on the map.

Comment: but your error exists because of `filterZoneHome` method. Look, you fetch your data, the result is just one object, and you run `this.filterZoneHome(zone)` (zone is an object), and inside this method you try to run `filter` on it (as I said, filter is **array** method). That's what this error means.